# Spring JdbcTemplate: Getting Lists Not Mapped to an Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I am using the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate in my Spring app.

I have a data bean object which will hold all my object attributes, "ApplicationVO". The first query, SELECT1_MAIN, populates the core attributes, others will be populated inside a For-loop for each result.

The first query is easy and returns a list of mapped objects (some fields are null). In the second one, I don't want to create separate data beans or any extra code. I want "anonymous" lists that I can step through and add values to my objects.

Some of the extra queries may return multiple fields. Is there an easy way to get anonymous lists without creating extra beans?

```
// Main Attributes
List<ApplicationVO> allEligibleApps = 
                jdbcTemplate.query(SELECT1_MAIN, paramMap, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(ApplicationVO.class));

// For each appl., fill out additional attributes
for (ApplicationVO appl: allEligibleApps)
{
     List l = jdbcTemplate.query(SELECT2_INFO, paramMap2, BeanPropertyRowMapper(ApplicationVO.class));
     appl.setInfoField1(l.get(0));
     appl.setInfoField2(l.get(1));          
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#queryForList%28java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource%29) method should do what you ask for.

Comment: Having said that, I'd recommend creating those entities.